# Stucco Cracks at Roof Line Causing Leaks

Tags: roof, leak, stucco

The stucco at the roof line is disintegrating causing leaks into the wall. We requested a quote from a roofing company thinking they could install a metal trim to cover the edge of the stucco. The roofer is now telling us we need to hire a stucco guy to repair the stucco. The holes are 3/4" or less. The house is 2 stories. I would think it would be easier and more effective to install a metal trim. And even if we could get a stucco guy to do this work, shouldn't it be done before they fix the leaks around the base of the chimney (where they are removing two rows of spanish tile)?  Any helpful comments would be appreciated. See rough sketch attached.
Thanks.

Comment: Stucco is not water barrier, the tarp under it it is

Comment: There's no sketch attached, you can [edit] your question then click the "sun & mountain" icon to attach it. NOTE: actual pics would probably be more helpful than a sketch... Also, it makes sense that a roofing company would defer to a stucco company for stucco repair. Additionally, trying to "fix" this by putting a band-aid of metal trim over it sounds like, well, a band-aid fix. I'd want the stucco properly repaired, then maybe add a metal band as a protective measure if the stucco company agreed that it would be helpful.